# How to create systemd unit file for phpbrew?

Tags: centos, systemd

I'd like to create a unit file for systemd which will autostart PHP FPM after server reboot.

Here is the file content:

```
[Unit]
Description=PHP 5.5.32 FPM

[Service]
User=deploy
Group=deploy
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/phpbrew use 5.5.32
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/phpbrew fpm start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I tried to start the service by runnint `sudo systemctl start php55-fpm.service` somehow it doesn't works.

Here is the output of `sudo systemctl status php55-fpm.service`

```
● php55-fpm.service - PHP 5.5.32 FPM
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php55-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2016-03-30 05:13:52 CDT; 3min 50s ago
  Process: 20444 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/phpbrew fpm start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20441 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/phpbrew use 5.5.32 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20444 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: sami     - http://get.sensiolabs.org/sami.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: phpcs    - https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcs.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: pdepend  - http://static.pdepend.org/php/latest/pdepend.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: onion    - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phpbrew/Onion/master/onion
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: box-2.5  - https://github.com/box-project/box2/releases/download/2.5.2/box-2.5.2.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: phpcov   - https://phar.phpunit.de/phpcov.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: phpcpd   - https://phar.phpunit.de/phpcpd.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: phpdcd   - https://phar.phpunit.de/phpdcd.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: phptok   - https://phar.phpunit.de/phptok.phar
Mar 30 05:13:52 web1 phpbrew[20444]: phploc   - https://phar.phpunit.de/phploc.phar
```

Additional information:

SELinux is disabled

```
[root@web1 deploy]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Is there anything that I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: SElinux could be the problem. 
I still encounter nearly the same with OpenVPN. There are several tutorials where you can create a new unit, but it won't work unless you disable SELinux.

Comment: Here are more specific details about SELinux:
https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: You might want to check the docs on the `type` [option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) for unit files. I suspect your service forks and as you've got your unit setup, Systemd doesn't yet know how to deal with that.

Comment: @mushroomer I will try to disable SELinux

Comment: @GregL I am not sure about I need to set `type` as `fork`

Comment: When you run `/usr/local/bin/phpbrew fpm start` (or `sudo /usr/local/bin/phpbrew fpm start`) does your terminal return, or does it sit there spitting out logs and details for the service?

Comment: @mushroomer the SELinux is already disabled

Comment: @GregL the terminal print out some text like "Starting.." and then return

Comment: Yeah, so it sounds like adding `Type=forking` to the `[Service]` section of your unit file will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpbrew 1.22.0 now supports `fpm setup --systemctl` command to help you setup the service.

Be sure to enable `--with-fpm-systemd` when building your [php](/questions/tagged/php).